# Is it possible to calculate a pseudo-R squared for a binomial GLMM with a cauchit link?

Tags: mixed-model, r-squared, link-function, cauchy-distribution, pseudo-r-squared

I'm modeling some repeated-measures presence-absence data using a binomial GLMM in lme4. I've been using the method suggested by Nakagawa and Schielzeth (2013) to calculate a marginal and conditional pseduo-$R^2$. According to their approach (if I'm understanding it correctly), for a model with an individual-level random effect, the marginal pseudo $R^2$ is

$R^2_m= \frac{\sigma^2_f} {\sigma^2_f+\sigma^2_\alpha+\sigma^2_e+\mu}$

where $\sigma^2_f$ is the variance of the fixed-effects component, $\sigma^2_\alpha$ is variance of the individual-specific effect, $\sigma^2_e$ is the additive dispersion, and $\mu$ is the distribution-specific variance. For a logit link, $\mu=\pi^2/3$ and for a probit link $\mu=1$.

I'm interested in using a cauchit link in my model, where the link function is defined as the CDF of the Cauchy distribution. However, as the Cauchy distribution has undefined variance, am I correct in assuming that I cannot use the approach above to calculate a pseudo-$R^2$?

Edit: the full citation is Nakagawa, S. and Schielzeth, H. (2013), A general and simple method for obtaining R2 from generalized linear mixed-effects models. Methods Ecol Evol, 4: 133–142. doi:10.1111/j.2041-210x.2012.00261.x

Comment: This is an interesting question, but I think it's quite fair to suppose that there's no such thing as a pseudo-R^2 for a model with a Cauchy distribution, for exactly the reasons you suggest. Maybe you could use a link function that's a t-distribution with 2 df (rather than 1 df, which corresponds to Cauchy)?

Comment: Thanks @BenBolker for confirming my suspicions. I'll look into using a t-distribution.

Comment: @yeticrab - Did you end up finding a solution to this with the t-distribution or another approach?

Comment: @DirtStats I ended up using the logit link after all for unrelated reasons, so unfortunately not.

Comment: +1 for the interesting question! What would you do for a Cauchit model with only fixed effects? That might be a good place to start.